# The following file could not be created since it already exists. Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: каждый раз, когда создаю новый проект, выдает следующее предупреждение:

```
The following file could not be created since it already exists: build.gradle

The following file could not be created since it already exists: .gitignore

The following file could not be created since it already exists: settings.gradle

The following file could not be created since it already exists: gradle-wrapper.jar

The following file could not be created since it already exists: gradle-wrapper.properties


If you proceed the resulting project may not compile or not work as intended.
```

Из-за чего это может происходить?

Comment: Файлы в итоге есть или нет?

Comment: @Эникейщик, нету